# In SSIS, is it possible to auto arrange items in a data flow task?

Tags: ssis

I'm building a project in SSIS. While the project works as I want it to work (that's what counts, right?), others are "bothered" by the "ugly" placement of the data flow tasks and the connector lines between them.

I manually moved the items to better locations on the map, but can only adjust the connector lines so much. The screenshot I included (which I hope you can see) shows you where things are now.

I tried looking for "Auto Arrange" or something similar and could find nothing in the menu bar or by right clicking. Is there some way to auto arrange the data task items so they look better?

I'm using SSIS 2012 if that makes any difference.

[image: Screenshot of SSIS Data Flow Task map]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So it appears that while there is -- technically speaking -- an Auto Layout feature, is not immediately accessible by right-clicking the diagram itself.

I found it by chance in what is to me the most unlikely of places:

**Format > Auto Layout > Diagram**

On selecting that menu choice, it arranges the diagram.  It does so well enough for me, but not well enough to satisfy others in my team who demand visual cleanliness.

Oh well.

Comment: The visual layout is just presentation. When the package runs "for real" on a server, it will be in an unattended fashion with no one to observe whether the data flows across the screen or uses the gravity assist by letting it fall down. Instead, tell your coworkers to focus on the problem being solved and the steps taken to solve it.

Comment: To that point, given your data flow, I see what is likely an unnecessary step with the Sort component. Why not let the database sort it, if required as it inserts it? Do you gain anything from having 4 files being read and inserted at once versus looping through 4 files and doing the insert per file? Performance of the later is likely going to be better and potentially have a lower maintenance cost

Comment: I used Sort because it is the only way I know of to make the final output distinct. Do you know of a way to make it distinct without using sort?  My search on the forums suggested using Sort.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes more sense and completely nullifies my earlier argument/approach. I completely forgot about the Sort component's ability to remove duplicates. I suppose if you knew there were no duplicates within a single source, then you could use lookups to load file after file. Given your current design, you're looking at either a Sort with remove duplicates or an Aggregate to get the unique set. I would probably rename the Sort to something like "Sort Dedupe set" so that it's clear without having to open the component to see what it is doing for the data flow. $.02

Comment: Good ideas. Seeing I only need a unique set -- I agree with using my ASP.NET page to handle the sorting -- I'll try Aggregate (which I haven't used yet). Thanks for the idea.