# How to get GraphLayout XML from programmatically generated SSIS package

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, dts

If you open a SSIS DTSX package in Visual Studio the Designer creates some additional 
DesignTimeProperties inside a CDATA block at the end of the package.

This looks like

```xml
<DTS:DesignTimeProperties >< ![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--This CDATA section contains the layout information of the package.The section includes information such as (x, y) coordinates, width, and height.-->
<!--If you manually edit this section and make a mistake, you can delete it. -->
<!--The package will still be able to load normally but the previous layout information will be lost and the designer will automatically re-arrange the elements on the design surface.-->
<Objects Version="8">
  <!--Each node below will contain properties that do not affect runtime behavior.-->
   <Package design-time-name="Package">
   <LayoutInfo >
     <GraphLayout Capacity="16" xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model.Serialization;assembly=Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Graph" 
          xmlns:mssgle="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph.LayoutEngine;assembly=Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph" 
          xmlns:assembly="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
          xmlns:mssgm="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph.Model;assembly=Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph">
       <NodeLayout
         Size="146.5,41.5"
         Id="Package\Datenflusstask"
         TopLeft="71.9999971389772,45.7600003636678" />
       <NodeLayout
         Size="155,41.5"
         Id="Package\Datenflusstask 1"
         TopLeft="126.666661633386,127.573334347195" />
   ....
```

The problem is, that this information is only added if the package is opened inside Visual Studio while added inside an 
Integration Services Project.

If I create a package with `ManagedDTS` programmatically this information is missing.

I did find the **SerializerHelper** class inside `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model.Serialization`
namespace in the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Graph.dll`, where you can call

```
var graphLayoutXml = SerializerHelper.Save(graphModelElement);
```

But unfortunately the coordinates are missing (NaN or 0,0..)

What I did right now is load the package in a string

```
string contents = String.Empty;
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package package = 
    new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package();
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("DemoPackageWithoutDesignTimeProperties.dtsx"))
{
    contents = r.ReadToEnd();
}
package.LoadFromXML(contents, null);
```

Then get the ControlFlowElements via

```
ControlFlowGraphModelElement controlFlowGraphModelElement = 
    new ControlFlowGraphModelElement();
controlFlowGraphModelElement.Initialize(package as IDTSSequence);
```

Afterward trying to get the GraphLayoutXml via

```
GraphModelElement graphModelElement = new GraphModelElement();
graphModelElement.Container = controlFlowGraphModelElement.Container;
var graphLayoutXml = SerializerHelper.Save(graphModelElement);
```

Obviously I'm missing some layouting. Can anyone help with the correct way...

I'm aware of several other classes in `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Graph.dll`, such as 
`LayoutGraph`, `GraphLayout` and `GraphControl` in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph.dll` but unfortunately the
documentation is not that useful..

Comment: I am missing the point in your question.  
You are asking **How to get GraphLayout XML from programmatically generated SSIS package**. This GraphLayout structure describes SSIS tasks and components layout and size in Visual Studio SSIS Designer; the layout is defined during package editing.  

When a Package is being generated programmatically, no designer layout is defined, since the Package is created outside the VS Designer. So, missing Layout section it is normal.
Perhaps, you want to ask how to read it in VS-created package where the Layout is present?

Comment: Hi Ferdipux! The point of the question is how to get the layout information with the correct coordinates. Visual Studio Designer also loads packages without the design time info and automatically arranges the tasks. I use ```var graphLayoutXml = SerializerHelper.Save(graphModelElement);``` but the resulting XML does not contain the correct coordinates. I guess I'm missing some layouting (perhaps GraphLayout.GetLayout(graphModelElement).ApplyLayout ... but I'm stuck here..
Thank you anyway!

Comment: Afaik, when VS opens a package without the layout information, it calls Autolayout procedure and creates the layout anew. After that is is saved in .dtsx file. Unfortunately, I cannot tell how VS (in terms of API and procedure calls) is doing that.

Comment: @PeterSchneider check my answer update, it may help

Comment: @Ferdipux Thanks for the great information. I didn't know before that layout is related to SSIS designer only.

Answer (score 2):

### Why it is not working?

First of all, I would like to start by @Fredipux great comments:

> This GraphLayout structure describes SSIS tasks and components layout and size in Visual Studio SSIS Designer; the layout is defined during package editing. When a Package is being generated programmatically, no designer layout is defined, since the Package is created outside the VS Designer

That's right!! The main point is that `Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS` are .NET wrappers that allow you to create and execute packages programmatically where the design is meaningless. If you refer to the [official SSIS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-programming-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) and you navigate through all the sections and subsections, you will note that only these three assemblies are mentioned, while other assemblies such as `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Graph.dll` are not mentioned since they are related to the Visual Studio designer.

You can simply note that the four mentioned assemblies belong to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts` namespace while the other is for `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices`.

### How to arrange tasks in Visual Studio?

Note that in Visual Studio, within the menu strip you can go to

```
Format >> Auto Layout >> Diagram
```

[image]

[Then all tasks in the control flow will be arranged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982852/in-ssis-is-it-possible-to-auto-arrange-items-in-a-data-flow-task).

In the official documentation, I searched within all properties and methods listed for ManagedDTS and other assemblies but I didn't find mentioned that you can use `AutoLayout()` method. In addition, I didn't find this option available even using ezApi and BIML.

Also, I tried to use Visual Studio object explorer to search for this method with no luck.

### Something to try

I think that the simplest way to add layout is to build the layout XML clause manually (take XML structure form an existing package and change the Id, size, and TopLeft properties) and add it to the package XML.

After running many examples, it looks like this is possible but very complicated when there are many connected tasks. In the following subsections, I illustrated some useful information about `GraphLayout` XML node and how to add information using a C# script:

#### GraphLayout XML node

I tried to create a console application that built the layout XML section and add it to the package. But before showing the code and experiment, I would like to illustrate some information about the Graphlayout XML.

The Graphlayout node is found within the following path in the XML:

```
DTS:DesignTimeProperties/Objects/Package/LayoutInfo/GraphLayout
```

It contains design information about all objects added within the control flow even precedence constraints connectors. Within this XML node you may find three types of nodes (maybe more):

1. NodeLayout: which describe tasks, as example:

   ```
     <NodeLayout
     Size="151,42"
     Id="Package\Data Flow Task"
     TopLeft="369,179" />
   ```
2. EdgeLayout: which describes precedence constraints connectors, and it is more complicated since it contains all information about the connector curves. As example:

   ```
   <EdgeLayout
     Id="Package.PrecedenceConstraints[Constraint]"
     TopLeft="308.5,125">
     <EdgeLayout.Curve>
       <mssgle:Curve
         StartConnector="{assembly:Null}"
         EndConnector="136,54"
         Start="0,0"
         End="136,46.5">
         <mssgle:Curve.Segments>
           <mssgle:SegmentCollection
             Capacity="5">
             <mssgle:LineSegment
               End="0,23" />
             <mssgle:CubicBezierSegment
               Point1="0,23"
               Point2="0,27"
               Point3="4,27" />
             <mssgle:LineSegment
               End="132,27" />
             <mssgle:CubicBezierSegment
               Point1="132,27"
               Point2="136,27"
               Point3="136,31" />
             <mssgle:LineSegment
               End="136,46.5" />
           </mssgle:SegmentCollection>
         </mssgle:Curve.Segments>
       </mssgle:Curve>
     </EdgeLayout.Curve>
     <EdgeLayout.Labels>
       <EdgeLabelCollection />
     </EdgeLayout.Labels>
   </EdgeLayout>
   ```
3. AnnotationLayout: which describe annotations. As example:

   ```
   <AnnotationLayout
     Text="This is an annotation"
     ParentId="Package"
     FontInfo="{assembly:Null}"
     Size="121,60"
     Id="edef7a97-4253-4bb8-907e-6079f42467c6"
     TopLeft="421,152" />
   ```

#### Experiment

I created a console application that builds the `DTS:DesignTimeProperties` section manually without adding the precedence constraints connectors information *(since it is complicated)*. I only tried to add information about two tasks having the following Id's:

1. Execute T-SQL Statement Task
2. Data Flow Task

These tasks were connected using a precedence constraint connector.

I used the following code to alter the package .dtsx file:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string package;
        string xmlLayout =  "  <DTS:DesignTimeProperties><![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n" +
                            "<!--This CDATA section contains the layout information of the package. The section includes information such as (x,y) coordinates, width, and height.-->\r\n" + 
                            "<!--If you manually edit this section and make a mistake, you can delete it. -->\r\n" +
                            "<!--The package will still be able to load normally but the previous layout information will be lost and the designer will automatically re-arrange the elements on the design surface.-->\r\n" +
                            "  <Objects\r\n" +
                            "  Version=\"8\">\r\n" +
                            "   <!--Each node below will contain properties that do not affect runtime behavior.-->\r\n" +
                             "  <Package\r\n" +
                            "    design-time-name=\"Package\">\r\n" +
                            "    <LayoutInfo>\r\n" +
                            "      <GraphLayout\r\n" +
                            "        Capacity=\"4\" xmlns=\"clr-namespace:Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Model.Serialization;assembly=Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Graph\" xmlns:mssgle=\"clr-namespace:Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph.LayoutEngine;assembly=Microsoft.SqlServer.Graph\" xmlns:assembly=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">";


        xmlLayout += "\r\n" + AddNodeLayout("Execute T-SQL Statement Task", 193, 83);

        xmlLayout += "\r\n" + AddNodeLayout("Data Flow Task", 369, 179);

        xmlLayout += "\r\n" +   "      </GraphLayout>\r\n" +
                                "    </LayoutInfo>\r\n" +
                                "  </Package>\r\n" +
                                "</Objects>]]></DTS:DesignTimeProperties>\r\n";

        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"G:\SSIS_Test\Integration Services Project1\Package3.dtsx"))
        {
            package = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

        package = package.Substring(0, package.LastIndexOf("</DTS:Executable>")) +
            xmlLayout + package.Substring(package.LastIndexOf("</DTS:Executable>"));

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"G:\SSIS_Test\Integration Services Project1\Package3.dtsx"))
        {
            sw.Write(package);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }

    static string AddNodeLayout(string TaskId, int x, int y)
    {

        return "        <NodeLayout\r\n" +
      "          Size=\"225,42\"\r\n" +
      "          Id=\"Package\\" + TaskId + "\"\r\n" +
      "          TopLeft=\"" + x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString() + "\" />";


    }

}
```

#### Results and discussion

The section was added successfully, but it doesn't make sense when opened the package in Visual studio since the tasks were not arranged as described (AutoLayout() was executed by Visual Studio)

[image]

I tried to remove the connector between both tasks and rerun the experiment, the  tasks were arranged successfully:

[image]

**This means that if any of the layouts of the objects of the tasks is not defined, Visual studio will ignore the added section and execute AutoLayout() function when the package is opened.**

Based on that, if you decided to go with this approach (or even with any other approach) , you have to know how `EdgeLayout` nodes can be generated.

---

### Update - Searching for AutoLayout() method

Based on your comments, you don't want to add each task location manually but you are looking to execute `AutoLayout()` method.

After checking the assemblies imported in your project, I did a small search using Object Explorer for `AutoLayout()` method. I think there are two relevant methods found:

- `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.View.BaseGraphControl.AutoLayout()`
- `Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.View.IGraphControlEx.AutoLayout()`

I don't know if they can be executed from C# script since they don't take any arguments. **I think that they are not built to be used from a C# script but they are internal methods for Visual studio.** But you can give a try.

[image]

*Note: In my opinion, executing this method programmatically is useless, since it will be executed by Visual Studio once the package is opened and it doesn't affect package execution at all*

Comment: Hi Hadi! Thank you very much for your contribution. Unfortunately the proposed solution requires to set the coordinates manually - what I wanted to avoid. You are completly right, that Visual Studio Designer calls the AutoLayout function. IMHO it should be possible to call this behavior by code as the assemblies are available and have public methods. I've prepared a [sample project](https://github.com/Peter-Schneider/GraphLayoutDemo) where you can see in more detail, where I'm stuck. I guess it's only a problem with initalizing the objects correctly.. Thank you once again for your answer!

Comment: @Peter i will check this project tonight and get back to you

Comment: @Peter I am checking the project right now. But why you need to do that if you agreed that it is related to Visual Studio and it will be executed one package is opened!! I think adding this information (without specifying location manually) is useless

Comment: @PeterSchneider I added an update about `AutoLayout()` function, I hope it will help. Good luck

Comment: Hi Hadi! Thank you for your update! The reason behind all this is, that I have many programmatically generated packages, and I wanted to build a webviewer for those using the DesignTimeProperties Info... I thought it would be easier to get the coordinates serialized... ;-/ Your help is very appreciated and I'll reward you the bounty! If I find a solution, I'll be back here...

Comment: Hi Hadi! Not yet.. ;-/